# Why do I need the Raging Intimidation feat in order to Demoralize while Raging?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, actions, barbarian, rage

While building a Barbarian, I was reviewing the rules for Rage and Intimidation. The Barbarian has a level 1 class feat called [Raging Intimidation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=132) that states:

> *While you are raging, your [Demoralize](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=53) and [Scare to Death](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=837) actions (from the Intimidation skill and an Intimidation skill feat, respectively) gain the rage trait, allowing you to use them while raging.*

But I don't see a good reason, beyond the existence of this class feat itself, why these actions would be otherwise forbidden during a Rage.

The [Rage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=3) action itself only specifies three restrictions, the relevant item being:

> *You can't use actions with the concentrate trait unless they also have the rage trait. You can Seek while raging.*

Both *Demoralize* and *Scare to Death*, the actions specifically called out by *Raging Intimidation*, **do not possess** the [Concentrate](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=32) trait. Also note that the *Rage* action itself does not state that actions require the [Rage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=135) trait. This trait only specifies that actions with the trait may only be used while raging. This does not imply the inverse since, if it did, a Barbarian would not be able to *Strike* while raging.

**What am I missing? Why could I not use *Demoralize* or *Scare to Death* without the *Raging Intimidation* class feat?**

*All citations and links are [Archives of Nethys](https://2e.aonprd.com/)*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Demoralize has the Concentrate Trait

This skill action does have the trait mentioned in Rage as not working, so giving it the rage trait does allow you to use it while raging. You are correct that Scare to Death lacks the concentrate trait and that any barbarian could use it while raging regardless of Raging Intimidation.

### Why Gain the Rage Trait?

Even though Scare to Death could be used by any barbarian, one with Raging Intimidation could use it as part of the free action [Mighty Rage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=4). This allows you to scare someone to death while also entering your rage, an action economy boost if there aren't any other abilities with the rage trait you'd rather use.

Comment: Man how did I miss that on Demoralize? Looked right through it somehow. Swear I checked haha